# Android Studio Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED] on Run

Tags: android, installation, apk, manifest

I experience this error when trying to test the app on my phone on Run. I dunno why this error pop out but I have try to do some fix based based on some solution from stack but it is not working.

my pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.wolex_000.freesim

MY Manifest code is:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.chat.freshim"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="0.1" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- FOR QB -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

<!-- For GCM -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- For GCM
<permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" /> -->

<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_fresh"
    android:label="fssl"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:label="fssl"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.FriendsListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.FriendsAllListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.FriendsDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.RegisterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.UserDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.StatusActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.SettingsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.EditProfileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.EditPasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.GroupCreateActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.GroupListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.GroupMessageDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.GroupChooseFriendListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.GroupDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.GroupEditMemberListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.UploadFileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.CountryCodesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.InviteFriends"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.AddContactFriend"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>

    <!-- QB ACTIVITY AND SERVICES -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.qb.ActivityVideoChat"
        android:label="fssl"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.qb.ActivityCallUser"
        android:label="fssl"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <service android:name="com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.service.QBVideoChatService"/>
    <!-- For GCM -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.chat.freshim.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.chat.imapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.chat.freshim.services.GcmIntentService" />

    <service android:name="com.chat.freshim.services.LoadImageService" />
    <service android:name="com.chat.freshim.services.LoadFileService" />

    <service android:name="com.chat.freshim.services.ResponseRequestService" />
    <service android:name="com.chat.freshim.services.FriendRequestService" />

    <service android:name="com.chat.freshim.services.DownLoadFileService" />
    <service android:name="com.chat.freshim.services.DownloadImageService" />

    <service android:name="com.chat.freshim.services.LastSeenGetService" />
    <service android:name="com.chat.freshim.services.LastSeenSetService" />

    <service android:name="com.chat.freshim.services.QbRegisterService" />

    <!--service android:name="com.quickblox.module.chat.videochat.VideoChatService"/-->

    <!-- For GCM -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        />

</application>
```

I have try some help but have not get the solution to it.

Comment: is that your full xml file.?  i dont see </manifest> end tag. Just wondering how you are able to compile it...

Comment: my manifest is included in the compile code. the issue is with the play-services

Comment: what do you mean by : my manifest is included in the compile code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<meta-data>` tag is missing the required `android:value` entry. It should read:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After adding @integer/google_play_services_version in the manifest I got an Error Error:(172, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version'). Then I added compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87' in my app gradle then I got an Error :appdexDebug

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        />
```